# python string(js variable type) to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

How do I convert this string to a dictionary

I'm trying regex `r"},\s\]"`, but didn't get the desired result.

**HTTP request body**

**Content-Type: text/html**

```
var sample = {
        "date": "2022. 03. 23. 16:18",
        "list":
                [
                         {
                                "name": "USD",
                                "var1":"1236.26",
                                "var2":"1193.74",
                                "var3":"1226.90",
                                "var4":"1203.10",
                                "var5":"1215.00"
                         },
                         {
                                "name": "JPY",
                                "var1":"1020.81",
                                "var2":"985.71",
                                "var3":"1013.09",
                                "var4":"993.43",
                                "var5":"1003.26"
                         },
                ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to get rid of any trailing commas:

```
_sample = sample.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",]", "]")
```

You can also use regex for this:

```
import re

_sample = re.sub(r",(\s)+]", "]", sample)
```

Then use `json.loads()` to parse it into a dict.

```
import json

outcome = json.loads(_sample)
```

**Beyond the OQ**
If it is also possible that we'd have trailing commas after the last key-value of a dictionary: e.g. `{"var5": "1215.00",}` you can update the above code to:

```
_sample = sample.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",}", "}").replace(",]", "]")
```

Or with regex:

```
regex = r"(,(\s)+]|,(\s)+})"
```

Comment: I know that json.loads conversion is not possible because of `,`.
I have a situation where I need to remove `,`

Comment: @6691a Why not be more specific about that in the question? Also your regex `r"},\s\]"` wont work unless there's a guarantee that the trailing comma is only between `}` and `]` and not for example on the last value of an inner dict

Comment: I'll think about it some more

Comment: The reason I couldn't explain in detail is because I'm not good at English.
Sorry about that.
The last one is unconditionally ended that way.

Comment: @6691a see edited answer with regex

Comment: Thank you. If the desired result did not come out, I thought about using beautifulsoup to get it, but I got the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

sample = """{
    "date": "2022. 03. 23. 16:18",
    "list":
    [
        {
            "name": "USD",
            "var1": "1236.26",
            "var2": "1193.74",
            "var3": "1226.90",
            "var4": "1203.10",
            "var5": "1215.00"
        },
        {
            "name": "JPY",
            "var1": "1020.81",
            "var2": "985.71",
            "var3": "1013.09",
            "var4": "993.43",
            "var5": "1003.26"
        },
    ]
}"""


to_dict = json.loads(sample)
```

Comment: Since this information is a value received through the http request, it is in a string state.

Comment: i didn't know that the value was received through an HTTP request, check the Updated Answer.

Comment: @6691a See my answer. `json.dump()` does not convert to `dict`

Comment: `loads` not `dump` little mistake :)

Comment: @LoneSamurai Now I'm really wondering, do you guys not see my answer from 35 mins ago? :)

Comment: @re-za i just saw :))))